# How to make the element in the middle fill remaining height - IE8 support?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

There are similar questions, and answers using `flexbox` (css3), or `table` (work for the last element only).

But how can I make the element in the middle fill remaining `height`, using css2 (for IE8)?

```css
 .parent {
   background: yellow;
   display: block;
   height: 200px;
 }
 .child {
   border: solid 1px #555;
 }
 .fill {
   height: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="child fill">
    2 (fill available height)
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    3
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tombrito/o089ssbm/1/)

Answer (score 1):

if you need IE8 support then use `display:table`/`table-row`

```css
.parent {
  background: yellow;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
.child {
  display: table-row;
}
.height{
  height: 20px /*change the value for what you like */
}
/*demo only */

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid #555
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child height">
    <div class="cell">
      1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="cell">
      2 (fill available height)
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child height">
    <div class="cell">
      3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually I want only item 2 to fill the remaining height. 1 and 3 should stay with minimum height needed to read.

Comment: so set a fix `height` in both, I'll updated my anwser

Comment: @TomBrito , go read about table-layout properties and find out that height expand to fit content,so you can safely set an height:0; to 1 & 3 ...

Comment: @TomBrito a flexible layout would be as my first answer, and this is still flexible on your `2`

Comment: Your first answer is flexible for item 3, I want for item 2. The current answer is hard coded. I want the second element to be 100% of whatever the remaining height of the parent container is. But I'll understand if it's not possible with css2.